# How to add extra/custom field in group-audience widget in content type in drupal commons

Tags: organic-groups, 7, entities

Here i am working in **group-audience widget in drupal commons**.Here i need one idea for adding extra/custom field in group-audience widget in content type.
[image: Post your New custom field in group audience]

Given image have two option value but i need to add extra option value in that group audience contents in every content type.Here i tried to change in that

> **manage field -> edit group audience -> add new field**

. But it will not shown in frontend content added form.And also i tried this way..

> **Configuration->Organic Groups-> OG Field Settings**

but i cant found the solution for this.I need to show/hide while change that group-audience radio button in content type.Kindly guide to create custom field through hook_function or any other methods.

**NOTE:**

1. Post under groups list
2. Post under trusted contact list
3. post under event List